# Laravel Echo how to handle connected, disconnected, reconnecting and etc

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, socket.io, vuejs2, laravel-echo

Does anyone know how to handle the connected, disconnected, reconnecting and etc on Laravel Echo?

I'm using VueJS btw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to connect you do this:

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

in your function or on load you then do this:

```
                window.Echo = new Echo({
                    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
                    host: socketServerURL, //whatever url you need
                    auth: {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getToken() }}
                });

                window.Echo.connector.socket.on('connect', function(){
                    this.isConnected = true
                })

                window.Echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                    this.isConnected = false
                })

                window.Echo.private('contacts').listen('ContactUpdated', event => {
                    console.log(event)
                })
```

Comment: The second chunk of code solved my problem for X-Socket-Id not found.

Comment: When you get disconnect event by the way?

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but I tried the selected answer with no success. I suppose maybe laravel echo updated some stuff since this was answered. I've found the correct and updated answer here:

[Binding callbacks on Laravel Echo with Laravel Websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153997/binding-callbacks-on-laravel-echo-with-laravel-websockets)

Comment: this only works for Pusher, how about Redis (Socket.io)